# My renders are stretched and I don’t know what I did to make it this way

Tags: rendering, mesh, camera

This is my first blender render ever. I spent a lot of time on it and I was correcting lighting issues and resizing the camera. When I did something (I have no idea what), it resulted in my models looking stretched when rendering them. I did use some downloaded assets. A plant, books and a background I believe. All of these don’t seem resized at all. The rest of the meshes I used are from Blender. How do I fix this?

[Download .blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qlmsr98f71rjiqy/torsoartcopy.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because of your render aspect ratio:

[image]

change this e.g. to 2:2 and it works.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: if my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer - thanks

Comment: I’m so dumb. I didn’t know about the check Mark. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. You are not dumb. Not knowing things isn’t dumb. Not learning is dumb 